# How to use if condition inside where clause in Sequelize.js

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I would like to query `ManufacturerId: manufacturer_id` only if `manufacturer_id` is not equal to null.

I tried this code but its giving me syntax error:

```
/* Get Brands List */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var archived_status = req.query["archived-status"];
  var manufacturer_id = req.params.manufacturer_id;
  models.Brand.findAll({
    where: {
        brand_archived_status: archived_status,
        if(manufacturer_id != null){
          ManufacturerId: manufacturer_id
        }
    },
    include: [{
      model: models.Job,
      required: false
    }]
  }).  
  then(function(brands) {  
      res.status(200).json(brands);  
  }, function(error) {  
      res.status(500).send(error);  
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just make whole `where` condition outside of `Sequelize` query , Here you go :

```
let where = {
    brand_archived_status: archived_status
};
if (manufacturer_id != null) {
    where['ManufacturerId'] = manufacturer_id
}

models.Brand.findAll({
    where,
    include: [{
        model: models.Job,
        required: false
    }]
})
```

This wil look clean and simple :)